# Using Button resources for different hover states

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm creating a button using a spritesheet in xaml by repositioning the translateX and translateY values of the button.

What I would like to do is change the translateX and translateY value on the state change, I'm sure this is possible in xaml but under blend it would allow me to change those x and y values as it says they are computed values (i don't want those values tweening, just changing upon hover)

Here's the example of the current single state button.

```
        <Button Content="test" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="57" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="294" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="R" Opacity="1" StrokeThickness="0" Visibility="Visible">
                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Project;component/wp7_buttons.png" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" >
                                                <ImageBrush.Transform>
                                                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-558" TranslateY="0"/>
                                                </ImageBrush.Transform>
                                            </ImageBrush>
                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
            <Button.Style>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="ButtonStyle1"/>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

How do I do this? I need to be able to bind each state to a property which will include the x and y translate values and also the ImageSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to work with **VisualStates** like below

in blend you cand edit a button template copy and you will see all its VisualStates.

so you just have to change `Storyboard.TargetName` and `Storyboard.TargetProperty` to match with your ImageBrush CompositeTransform :)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid x:Name="Root">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                    <VisualTransition To="Pressed" />
                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" />
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" To="0" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" To="1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" To="0.25" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Opacity)" To="1" />
```

Comment: that combined with having the element duplicated for each state that you need. I was over complicating things by trying to change an integer value.

Comment: you shouldn't duplicate element. play with the `DoubleAnimation` according to the state : name your `CompositeTransform` then use it in the `Storyboard.TargetName`, set `Storyboard.TargetProperty=TranslateX` and `To="-558"`, etc..